# How wifi sense actually connects to any network?

Tags: wifi, windows-10

I read that using Wi-Fi  sense, we can share our Wi-Fi  networks with others and it stores pre-shared keys on Microsoft servers. Please help me understand the below scenario:

I am sharing my network (using Wi-Fi  sense) and my Facebook friend who uses windows 10 comes over. How does that person connect to my network automatically if he/she is not connected to any network in the first place? How will my Wi-Fi key be sent to that person's machine before even connecting to the network?

Answer (score 1):

> How does that person connect to my network automatically if he/she is
>   not connected to any network in the first place?

From [Wi‑Fi Sense FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/wi-fi-sense-faq) in section *What does Wi-Fi sense do?*, it says that your friend can connect to your network **only after** he has   shared at least one network with his contacts.

> How will my Wi-Fi key be sent to that person's machine before even
>   connecting to the network?

It comes down from a Microsoft server in **encrypted** form, and is decrypted behind the scenes.

He won't receive it **until** he tries to get connected to your network. I think it is better if I quote you directly this from the FAQ I mentioned. It shows how Wi-Fi sense determines available Wi-Fi hotsports to which your friend may connect to your shared network:

> Wi‑Fi Sense has a database of information about open Wi‑Fi
>   hotspots—and we update that crowdsourced information based on what
>   your PC and other participating customers' PCs tell us about those
>   networks. Wi‑Fi Sense analyzes some characteristics of open Wi‑Fi
>   networks that other Windows customers have connected to and determines
>   if they had a good-quality connection. If enough of them did, those
>   networks are added to the database and are suggested by Wi‑Fi Sense.
>   You and others then get connected to a suggested network when one of
>   them is in range.

The very detailed process is not something Microsoft will publish.

Comment: But how will the key be sent in encrpyed form if my friend's machine is not connected to internet?

Comment: @user1004985 Check my edit and hopefully you understand the logic

Comment: I still didnt understand completely. Does this mean that a list of Wi-Fi credentials in encrypted form will be stored locally?